# Replacing Buttons with Hyperlinks, Suitable JQuery Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have following script which is fully functional

HTML Source

```
<div id="filters">
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".trans">trans</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="mix metal trans"><h3 class="name">Mercury</h3></div>
  <div class="mix trans "><h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3></div>
  <div class="mix metal "><h3 class="name">Alminium</h3></div>
</div>
```

It works with following JQuery without any problem

```
$( function() {
  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('#container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.mix',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });
  // filter functions
  var filterFns = {
  };
  // bind filter button click
  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });
});
```

I want to replace

```
<div id="filters">
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".trans">trans</button>
</div>
```

with

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#" class="filter is-checked" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".metal">metal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".trans">trans</a></li>
</ul>
```

for some reason after I replace it doesn't work as it should be. I think I'm doing something wrong with following code in JQuery. Please support me to fix this.

```
  // bind filter button click
  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });
```

FYI: I'm implementing Isotope code to my project.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just amend the HTML source directly? Hacking the DOM around like this is never a good thing to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the button passed as scope in click function, remove it and replace with the correct one

```
$('#filters').on( 'click', '***button<-- change this***', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });
```

the second parameter that you send in on function is the selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

Refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/)